# Screen reader reads list items multiple times

Tags: html, angular, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I'm trying to make a project fully accessible, but the screenreader reads some elements from my list multiple times.

*Edit: It seems this issue only happens in google chrome*

this is the source code:

```
<ul class="o-contact__list">
    <li *ngIf="page?.result?.fields?.contactAddress">
        {{ page?.result?.fields?.contactAddress }}
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="page?.result?.fields?.contactEmail">
        {{ page?.result?.fields?.contactEmail }}
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="page?.result?.fields?.contactTel">
        {{ page?.result?.fields?.contactTel }}
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="page?.result?.fields?.contactPrice">
        {{ page?.result?.fields?.contactPrice }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the HTML output:

```
<ul class="o-contact__list">
    <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "mainstreet 123"}--><li>
        mainstreet 123
    </li>
    <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "info@email.com"}--><li>
        info@email.com
    </li>
    <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "tel.: 555 7125"}--><li>
        tel.: 555 7125
    </li>
    <!--bindings={"ng-reflect-ng-if": "free"}--><li>
        free
    </li>
</ul>
```

For some reason the first item gets read 3 times. The 2 following items get read twice, and the last item only gets read 1 time.

Comment: what screen reader?  only happens in chrome, not ie or ff?  how are you navigating to the list with the screen reader?  with a shortcut key such as 'L' or 'I' (eye) or the down arrow walking the DOM?

Comment: I use voice over on a Mac, I have tested it on safari and ff and both read the list normally. I also tested on chrome with ChromeVox and that gives no issues so I assume its a voice over and chrome combination that causes the problem. I navigate the page using the voice over command (ctrl + alt) and the left and right arrows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem lay in the styling.
The list-items had a `::before` which cause the issue with the multiple readings. I changed it to `::after` which solved the problem .
I don't know exactly why this is tho so if someone still know the answer to this I would love to hear!

Comment: We would need to see the CSS in order to know (not to mention the compiled HTML, not the Angular 'prefab' code). Otherwise it's impossible to tell.